# How to Activate/Deactivate Options from Different Scene

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a snake game in Unity where I have the ability to vibrate the phone every time the player eats an apple. However, I have a Menu scene and a settings page (In the Menu scene) and I want to be able to turn on and off the vibrate on the phone.

This is how the Vibrate works:
[image]

This is what the settings menu looks like. The Vibrate Option is a toggle.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) for this purpose. You can think of them as cookies. You can use [setInt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html) method in order to set a value for vibration in the settings. As an example:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Vibration", 0);
```

Then in the game you can get the value and compare using an if conditional:

```
int vibrate = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Vibration");
if (vibrate == 0){...}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm very confused so in my vibration script I put in PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Vibration", 0); then in my GameManager script I put in the int but where do I put the if statement?

Comment: You should call the setInt when the player enables/disables the vibration in settings/game manager file (I don't know which file you are using for that). Then you can use getInt, in your vibration script to get vibration setting and use in in if conditional such as, if vibration != 0 then vibrate. (You will also need to handle the default case, when player doesn't change any option.)